I am trying to download tailscale on Rasberry Ppi, getting follow error
Error:
 pacman -S tailscale-pikvm
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) tailscale-1.72.1-1  tailscale-pikvm-0.7-1

Total Download Size:    8.99 MiB
Total Installed Size:  33.27 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
 tailscale-1.72.1-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz failed to download
 Total (1/2)                                                                                         9.0 MiB  64.2 MiB/s 00:00 [#############################################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'tailscale-1.72.1-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.archlinuxarm.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to retrieve some files)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

I saw on the website that there is no 1.72 version available, it`s actually tailscale-1.76.6-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz.
So how I pull this version from the website?

Try updating all packages sudo pacman -Syu and then install tailscale-pikvm again sudo pacman -S tailscale-pikvm.
